# Python or Perl script to run desired commands in another OS

Tags: linux, ssh, batch-file

Currently i am working on Windows OS, i have a batch file. Using batch file i can up the SSH client then i can connect to other Linux based OS. This particular OS has a command prompt, but there is no GUI, to give inputs, so i want to write a Perl or Python script in Windows, then i will embed this to batch file to execute commands over there. is it possible? if so i need Perl or Python script for this. In any other script, if this is possible, then tell me. I  am not restricted to particular script.

Comment: Could you clarify what you want to achieve? Do you want to connect to another machine via `ssh` and then run a command on the remote machine?

Comment: i have a board, it is connected to one router(which has a terminal). I can run commands in that terminal, like these commands are inputs for that board, then the board will process the commands, then it will give the output, i can see in that terminal. Now, i can up this terminal by using a batch file in windows(i.e. can connet, can up SSH client using batch file). I need a script to run commands in this terminal, from my windows itself (like input automation). are you clear?

Comment: Sorry, I still don't get it.

Comment: What me and my friend wanna do is we are provided with an embedded system which hosts an operating system(linux based). Using Ayera Teraterm we could connect to that embedded system. using teraterm scripts we could do some tests as well. lets i cannot key in anything on teraterm now is there any other chance by which we can execute the tests using any sort of scripts???

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run commands in the way you describe on a remote machine, in your case the board, there are several options:

One would be to use a here script from the terminal (listing logs the in this example)

```
$ ssh user@remote_name_or_ip <<"ENDOFCMD"
echo "Logs from " $(uname -a)
ls -ltr /var/log/*.log
ENDOFCMD
```

Alternatively you could place the script of your choice on the remote machine and run it via the ssh connection:

```
$ ssh user@remote_name_or_ip yourScript.sh
```

or if they are as uncomplicated as the first example, just run them directly:

```
$ ssh user@remote_name_or_ipssh 'echo $(uname -a); ls -ltr /var/log/*.log'
```

Comment: I am rewriting the entire question, study carefully., Is it possible to use a batch file to establish a ssh session with only an ip, send some commands by using script files and can we have the output written to a file or at least on terminal (to which we are connected, ssh session) ?

Comment: I assume you mean without entering a password during connection, if so  it is possible.  You'll need to set up authentication key pair, which is quite straight forward.  [See here](http://www.linuxproblem.org/art_9.html) for the steps.

Comment: :: this is not at all my problem, i can connect to the terminal, but i want to run commands, from my host itself with any scripting(incorporating commands into the script file), then it will execute automatically with batch file(i will include this script file in my batch file). This is what my problem is..!

Comment: It would probably be best to edit the question so it is clear to everyone what you want to achieve and what you think the problem is.  Use screen grabs if you think it will be easier.

Answer (score 0):

Easily done using `plumbum`.  See [here](http://plumbum.readthedocs.org/en/latest/remote.html).